# Using .net 8, Blazor and FluentUI - Set accentFillRest value

Tags: .net, blazor-server-side, fluent-ui

I using the out-of-the-box setup for Blazor and FluentUI. My only goal is that the banner on top should have a specific color. I noticed that the color is set using CSS like this:

`background-color: var(--accent-fill-rest);`

How and where do I set the variable --accent-fill-rest? I don't care if the other color scheme will change as long as this variable has a specific color.